# Not able to login into Server using Login Keyword in SSH Library Robot Framework.Getting "timeout: timed out"

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I struck in one problem while using SSH Library in robot framework. While Using Login Keyword from SShlibrary. I am getting below error:

> KEYWORD SSHLibrary . Login ${USERNAME}, ${PASSWORD}, delay = 120
> Documentation:     Logs into the SSH server with the given username and
> password.
>
> Start / End / Elapsed:    20220922 23:57:29.686 / 20220922 23:57:32.703 /
> 00:00:03.017 23:57:29.686 INFO    Logging into '81.45.90.22:22' as
> 'xxxxxx'.
> **
>
> ***23:57:32.697   FAIL    timeout: timed out***
>
> **     23:57:32.703   INFO    ${Display} = False

My Questions are as of below:

1. How to login into Server without getting timed out error every time using SSH library ?
2. Why I am getting timed out in this case ?
3. How to give fiewall server as an argument in Login Method ?

Please find below code:

```
login
...     ${USERNAME}
...     ${PASSWORD}
...    delay = 120
```

Comment: Are you able to login to the same server with the same user / password from the command line?

Comment: When I try to connect to port 22 I see no connectivity, and it times out: `$ telnet 81.45.90.22 ssh`. Your client might be on the other side of some firewall. But perhaps not. Your attempted login session will timeout if the server is down, or if an intervening firewall is discarding your port 22 packets.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman - Yes i am able to login into that. The problem is even delay argument in Login Keyword is working or not i am not sure

Comment: When connecting manually, have you set a specific keepalive packet interval? Since you have not specified one for the Robot, the server might just close the connection during your delay.

Comment: SSHLibrary uses paramiko to establish connection. Use python with paramiko, in debug mode you should be able to see exactly why you are not successfull with your connection.

Comment: @JiriJanous - Problem is I am logging into the server that contains Firewall. So how to give firewall Server as an argument in Login Method ?